# Read files for part by part for 1000 bytes in PHP

Tags: php, file

I want to read a file line by line and add it into a variable till its string length is 1000 bytes . The file is relatively large, 
Hence, what I am doing is

```
if(file_exists($file)
{
    $fh = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($fh) or strlen($chunk) < 10001)
    {
         $line = fgets($fh, 1000);
         $chunk = $chunk."**".$line;
     }
 }
```

Issue is how does I store each chunk into an array index till I encounter end of file ?

Comment: Consider using `&&` rather than `or` and testing for `< 1001` rather than `10001`

Comment: this might still cause issues if the memory allocated to PHP scripts is lower than the file size - you'd simply run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
if(file_exists($file)
{
    $fh = fopen($file, "r");
    $chunks = array();
    while(!feof($fh) or strlen($chunk) < 10001)
    {
         $line = fgets($fh, 1000);
         // add line to the buffer            
         $chunks []= $line;
     }
 }
```

? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This gets only single lines from file. I want to read from file like

     line1....
     line2.....
     .
     .
     .
     line n  
total size of upto line n be less than or equal to 1000 bytes